# Camel stops consuming when Windows 2012 Server User is Locked

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, windows-server-2012, spring-jms

My Apache Camel 2.12.2 stops consuming from JMS queue when user that runs the process (on Windows Server 2012) lock the account. Everything works fine as long as the user is active.

What can I do to prevent this side effect?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely the operating system that is doing this. The question is how you are running the camel routes. If it is in an application server or something like ServiceMix, run the server as a "Windows Service" rather than in a user account. This will allow it to run in the background just fine. For most application server platforms like tomcat, jboss, glassfish, and servicemix how to run as a service is documented in their documentation.

Comment: I will try this solution and let you know if it helped.